# indexOf to Check for Irregular Combo Entries Not Working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, indexof

I have the following JavaScript to check for combo entries:

```
var proteins = [
    "charred sirloin steak", 
    "roasted salmon", 
    "grilled chicken", 
    "grilled salmon", 
    "jerk chicken",
    "miami ribs", 
    "charred steak", 
    "tandoori chicken supreme"
];

var sides = [
    "israeli couscous salad",
    "kale caesar", 
    "field o greens",
    "grilled broccoli",
    "greek salad", 
    "coconut curry quinoa salad",
    "vegetable egg fried rice",
    "general tao brussel sprouts",
    "tokyo slaw",
    "mac cheese",
    "potato salad"
];

var comboEntries = document.querySelectorAll('.combo-display .combo-item');
for (var i = 0; i < comboEntries.length; i++) {
  if (proteins.indexOf(comboEntries[i].innerText) == -1 || sides.indexOf(comboEntries[i].innerText) == -1) {
    comboEntries[i].style.color = "orangered";
    console.log(comboEntries[i].innerText + " is not a regular combo item.");
  }
}
```

However, this output all the `comboEntries` as irregular items. If I reverse the condition to `!= -1` I can see it working properly, highlighting regular items while excluding irregulars.

What am I doing wrong here? It must be something simple I've failed to recognize.

Edited: Sorry, I didn't include the HTML before because this is part of an online kitchen display screen which generates the content. Here's an example:

```
<div class="combo-display">
<p><strong>Protein 1:</strong> <span id="protein-1" class="combo-item">Custom item</span></p><div class="item-count"> x <span>1</span></div>
<p><strong>Protein 2:</strong> <span id="protein-2" class="combo-item">Custom item</span></p><div class="item-count"> x <span>1</span></div>
<p><strong>Protein 3:</strong> <span id="protein-3" class="combo-item">grilled chicken</span></p><div class="item-count"> x <span class="grilled-chicken-counter">1</span></div>
<p><strong>Side 1:</strong> <span id="side-1" class="combo-item">Custom item</span></p><div class="item-count"> x <span>1</span></div>
<p><strong>Side 2:</strong> <span id="side-2" class="combo-item">kale caesar</span></p><div class="item-count"> x <span class="kale-caesar-counter">1</span></div>
<p><strong>Side 3:</strong> <span id="side-3" class="combo-item">field o greens</span></p><div class="item-count"> x <span class="field-o-greens-counter">1</span></div>
</div>
```

So `custom item` should be highlighted as irregular items

Comment: where is HTML code?

Comment: can u post html code

Comment: Instead of using `||` try `&&`.

Comment: @JM-AGMS yes that works! It's always the simple thing I missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your question is not clear due to missing HTML code but if I m not wrong then you are trying to **highlight** the **value** that are neither in `proteins`  nor in `sides`.

For this you should use  `&&` in your `if condition`.

Here is a working snippet:

```js
var proteins = [
    "charred sirloin steak", 
    "roasted salmon", 
    "grilled chicken", 
    "grilled salmon", 
    "jerk chicken",
    "miami ribs", 
    "charred steak", 
    "tandoori chicken supreme"
];

var sides = [
    "israeli couscous salad",
    "kale caesar", 
    "field o greens",
    "grilled broccoli",
    "greek salad", 
    "coconut curry quinoa salad",
    "vegetable egg fried rice",
    "general tao brussel sprouts",
    "tokyo slaw",
    "mac cheese",
    "potato salad"
];

var comboEntries = document.querySelectorAll('.combo-display .combo-item');
for (var i = 0; i < comboEntries.length; i++) {
  if (proteins.indexOf(comboEntries[i].innerText) == -1 && sides.indexOf(comboEntries[i].innerText) == -1) {
    comboEntries[i].style.color = "orangered";
    console.log(comboEntries[i].innerText + " is not a regular combo item.");
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="combo-display">
  <div class="combo-item">
   israeli couscous salad
  </div>
  <div class="combo-item">
   vegetable egg fried rice
  </div>
  <div class="combo-item">
   vegetable egg fried rice1
  </div>
  <div class="combo-item">
   roasted salmon
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works! Don't know why I didn't tried something as simple as changing the `OR` condition to `AND`. Thank you!

Comment: ..It happens :)